# how to create excel file from HTML

Tags: javascript, xpages

There are too many examples how to create EXCEL file, like this:
[create Excel with xPages](http://kramkumarmca.blogspot.com/2012/01/export-documents-to-excel-using-xpages.html)

But I really need Excel xlsx format not xls. Just defining xlsx file extension and change content type doesn't help:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Comment: It seems like, lotus notes Domino server doesn't support new doc formats like xlsx

Comment: it's just pure JavaScript

Comment: nope, your example about xPages, it is similar to JSF from Java World. xPages to generate files, uses Apache POI framework under the hood. JS code just  interprets by the server

Comment: Take a look at Apache POI and XSSFWorkbook which is used to generate Excel spreadsheets in the xlsx format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vlad,
Setting the content type to xls or xlsx has the same effect: it tells the browser to hand over to Excel. It still would send HTML that excel renders. 
It is up to the user to save as xlsx.

If you really need a ready made xlsx you need to create an [XAgent](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2008/12/xagents-web-agents-xpages-style.html) that renders the binary xlsx format. The easiest way is Apache POI library, which is available for XPages [through OpenNTF](https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/).

Check the samples there. They should do what you need.